# Can I make the Skeptics chat the default?

Tags: support

Whenever I go to chat.stackexchange.com, or try to create a new chat room between myself and another user, the room always ends up being assigned to IT Security.

This is not very useful, when the other user may not belong to IT Security and especially when the topic of the chat is in no way related to IT Security.

Is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up your chat profile, click [change] next to your parent profile, and type in Skeptics.

[image: chat user parent user]

Future chat rooms created by you will default to that association.